# fit QGraphicsScene to QGraphicsView

Tags: qt, c++11

I'm trying to draw a stacked bar graph on Qt, i followed the tutorial on the documentation but when i try to put the graph inside a `QGraphicsView` i get a lo of unused space and can't manage to make the scene fit the view.

My code is the same as the documentation one plus the following to make the scene show up in the view:

```
QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
scene->addWidget(chartView);
ui->view->setScene(scene);
```

And what i get is this

[image]

As you can see there is a lot of unused space and it makes the text disappear, i wanted to make the graph fit the view but i can't seem to find a way to do so.

I tried in many different ways using

```
ui->view->ensureVisible ( scene->sceneRect() );
ui->view->fitInView( scene->sceneRect(),Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
```

and

```
ui->view->setSceneRect(0,0,ui->view->frameSize().width(),ui->view->frameSize().height());
```

but nothing seems to work (the second solution just moves the graph to the top left)

Comment: Are you doing this in the Widget constructor?

Comment: @vaultah no, i have a function inside the qwidget that gets called from mainwindow and draws the graph

Comment: @vaultah i jjust tried to put it into the constructor but i get the same result

Comment: Are you sure it's the `QGraphicsScene` and/or `QGraphicsVew` that's the problem?  From the image you show it appears that `chartView` has an incorrect [`sizeHint`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizeHint-prop) or [`sizePolicy`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop) causing the text to be clipped.  What does `chartView` look like if you just show it as a top level window at a size corresponding to its `sizeHint`?

Comment: @G.M. copying exactly the example on the documentation (with the graph at the center of mainwindow) the graph has the correct sizes

Comment: @G.M. thanks, i figured out that the problem was indeed the chartView size like you said. If you write an answer i can mark it as correct

Comment: @JohnSmith You may also consider creating an answer yourself if G.M. doesn't do it. You can upvote his comment and/or mention him (briefly) in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment... the real issue is the basic sizing of `chartView` rather than anything to do with `QGraphicsView` or `QGraphicsScene`.

When a `QWidget` is added to a `QGraphicsScene` the resulting `QGraphicsProxyWidget` will generally honour the size hint and policy of that widget.

In addition, though, the `QGraphicsScene` will set the scene rect to the bounding rectangle of all scene items and the `QGraphicsView` will then position the scene according to whatever [viewport anchor](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#resizeAnchor-prop) is in force.  The end result can be visually misleading if the scene has a complex set of items or has a bounding rectangle smaller than that displayed within the `GraphicsView`.

So if a widget does look odd when added to a `QGraphicsScene` it's normally a good idea to test by just showing it as a top level window on the desktop and make sure it behaves as expected before going any further.